# Revising the rates in a row/Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take the ratio of the target variable and distribute it to other non-zero variables in the same line, by their own weight. Can you help with this?

I want to make a row sum 100% including the target variable. I want to take the ratio of the target variable and distribute it to other variables. I want the rates to be 100% again. (target will be zero)

[image: data]

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding exactly what you want to accomplish.  It might help to have an example of the data you start with and how the same data looks after it's operated on.

Comment: Have you written any code yet? If so, please present it and let us know what isn't working. Are you familiar with Python? If not, you might want to start with a bit of learning on that.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is just normalization of the rows:

```
no_target = df.columns != 'target'
norm = df.loc[:, no_target].sum(axis=1) # sum of all values except target
df.loc[:, no_target] /= norm * 100
df['target'] = 0
```

Comment: Problem solved. I am aware that I am asking questions in a way that does not follow the rules, sorry again. I am new to Pyton programming and since I was dealing with a very tiring machine learning project, I guess I rebelled a bit and asked questions without running too much :) I apologize again and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be asking how to split the target value by the percentages in each column, replacing the percent value `x` with the `target * x`.  You could do this by iterating over each percentage value and multiplying by the target.  Zero is not a special case because `0 * target = 0`.  After each item in each row is changed, set the corresponding target value to zero.  If the sum of the original column values is 1 before multiplying, the sum of each of the columns after multiplying will be equal to the former target.

If I'm not understanding you question, please post more details including what you have tried so far.